# Displaying 2 colums in pivot chart in seperate groups

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have 2 value columns **Vehicle In** and **Vehicle Out**. When i create a pivot chart out of it (clustered Column). It displays as usual like this **in|out in|out**. But is there a way to make it display all the ins first and then all outs like **in|in|in out|out|out**

```
IN   OUT
10   123
23   32
123  32 
321  45
```

and so i'm trying to display it like this

```
10 | 23 | 123 | 321 | 123 | 32 | 32 | 45
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service but a community of people interested in computers that are willing to share their knowledge and experience. If you have already tried something please post it here, otherwise this question might get closed.

Comment: Can you share sample data used for creating your pivot table in addition to a mock visualization of the desired chart?

Comment: I am afraid this need could not be achieved by pivot table chart.